# Name of tool to insert ROMEX in friction connection

Tags: electrical

[image]

What is the name of this tool?
Is it on Amazon?

Comment: Bear with me... Can you link an example of what you mean by "Romex"? Can you link the device you are trying to attach the wires to? You can [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: When you say friction connector are you talking about a stab or backstab?

Comment: please can you link the video so we can see all the parts involved and not just a black oblong

Comment: No idea what a "friction type connector" is for Romex (Type NM cable, Romex is a brand name...)